# validate OCC option symbol through Bloomberg data licence

Tags: api, bloomberg

I am receiving OCC option symbols from the thirdparties. I need to validate the OCC option symbol from Bloomberg data licence.

Can we validate the OCC symbol from Bloomberg without the need to knowing the yellowKey/market sector.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'validate'? What are you trying to check / do?

Answer (score 0):

The OCC option symbol consists of 4 parts:

Root symbol of the underlying stock or ETF, padded with spaces to 6 characters
Expiration date, 6 digits in the format yymmdd
Option type, either P or C, for put or call
Strike price, as the price x 1000, front padded with 0s to 8 digits

So you can write a function and effectively parse each token based on the index and validate from a valid symbol perspective. But it is possible the given PUT or CALL might not exist in the market.

Refer to the following link for more information.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_symbol